# python array of decimals into binary numbers efficienty

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, data-conversion

I made a code that reads 256x256 matrix in a file, convert them to binary numbers, read portions of them to make two other files of 256x256 matrix. I think it's doing what I want, but it takes several minutes to process one file. Any suggestions for more efficient code?

Here's my code.

```
#Read in file
f = open(path, 'r')
l = [list(map(int, line.split(' '))) for line in f]
a = np.array(l)
A = a.ravel()

#Convert to binary
bnry = ()
for data in A:
    bnry = np.append(bnry, bin(data))

#Extract two data from each number and store them to 'THL' and 'THH'
thl = ()
thh = ()
THL = ()
THH = ()
for ths in bnry:
    thl = int(ths[2:14], 2)
    THL = np.append(THL, thl)
    thh = int(ths[-12:], 2)
    THH = np.append(THH, thh)

#Save 'THL' and 'THH' to text files
np.savetxt('THL.txt', np.reshape(THL, (256,256)), fmt='%.4g', delimiter=' ')
np.savetxt('THH.txt', np.reshape(THH, (256,256)), fmt='%.4g', delimiter=' ')
```

Solution
Much thanks to Oliver W., I was able to get a much shorter code performing whole lot faster than my several minutes long code. They are basically

```
thl = np.bitwise_and(a, 2**12 - 1)
thh = np.bitwise_and(a, (2**12-1) << (12+4)) >> (12+4)
```

I still need to study more and familiarize with how they work, but they are working great!

Comment: Couple of questions: Are you just aiming at speed, or is memory an issue? Do you know the range of decimals?

Comment: Have you done any profiling to determine the bottlenecks?

Comment: I thought if code takes less memory, then it'd work faster and vice versa. If not, speed would be better even if it takes more memory. As for profiling, I take it you mean at which step it takes long time? It's the for loop saving 'bnry'.

Comment: Ah, the initial decimal can go up to 268374015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to extract the first 12 bits of a series of integers and also the last 12. These are 2 distinct problems. The latter is the easiest.

First, let's start by using `numpy`'s convenience methods to read in the data from the text file, rather than concocting our own (more likely less optimal) functions:

```
a = np.fromfile(file, dtype=np.uint32, sep=' ')  # alternative: np.genfromtxt
```

Next, let's tackle the easy problem: extracting the lowest 12 bits from a:

```
THH = np.bitwise_and(a, 2**12 - 1)
```

This is a vectorized operation, so it's very efficient and blazingly fast.

Getting the first 12 bits is a whole other problem however, as it depends on the numbers themselves. My guess is that this is not actually what you want to do, but that someone has asked you to extract the 12 "highest" bits from some integers, when they are interpreted as having a fixed number of bits. An explanation with "the 3 highest bits" will make it more clear:

If you need the 3 highest bits of a number, let's say 20, you could interpret 20 as being written like `0b10100`, in which case the 3 highest bits are `101`, which is the decimal number 5. However, if you interpreted 20 as `0b0010100`, so with 2 leading zeroes, the 3 highest bits would be `001`, which is the decimal number 1. There aren't many operations that actually require you to take the length of the (smallest) binary representation into account, and I guess this is also why you say "I think it's doing what I want".

So, more likely, your numbers are to be interpreted in binary format with a fixed length. Looking at the largest value you mention, 268374015, that length is probably 28 digits (and even that seems unlikely, 32 bits is more common). But, assuming it is 28 bits, and you want only to extract the first 12, you could use the same trick as before:

```
np.logical_and(a, (2**12 - 1)<<16) >> 16
```

Note that `>>` and `<<` are [bitshift operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

I am making several assumptions about your data though (that you're dealing only with integers is clear, as you're converting everything with `int()`)  and of course, your *real* problem.

However, if you *really* want the first 12 bits from those numbers, starting from the most significant bit, then the following code shows you:

1. a reimplementation of your for-loops, slightly more efficient (`method_old()`)
2. a vectorized implementation of that algorithm (`method_new()`)

And their execution times on my machine.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random_integers(0, 268374016, (512,512))

def method_new(nbr_select_bits=12):
    high_bits = np.empty_like(a)
    for bit in range(32, nbr_select_bits -1, -1):
        mask = a < 2**bit
        shift = bit - nbr_select_bits
        bitmask = (2**nbr_select_bits - 1) << shift
        high_bits[mask] = np.bitwise_and(a[mask], bitmask) >> shift
    low_bits = np.bitwise_and(a, 2**nbr_select_bits - 1)
    return high_bits, low_bits

def method_old(nbr_select_bits=12):
    thl = np.empty(a.size, dtype=np.uint32)
    thh = np.empty(a.size, dtype=np.uint32)
    for enu, data in enumerate(a.ravel()):
        thl[enu] = int(bin(data)[2:2+nbr_select_bits], 2)
        try:
            thh[enu] = int(bin(data)[-nbr_select_bits:], 2)
        except ValueError:  # because 'int("b11", 2)' fails
            thh[enu] = int(bin(data)[-(nbr_select_bits+1):], 2)
    return thl.reshape(a.shape), thh.reshape(a.shape)

from timeit import timeit
new_t = timeit('method_new()', setup='from __main__ import method_new', number=1)
old_t = timeit('method_old()', setup='from __main__ import method_old', number=1)
print('Old method ran in {:.2f}ms,\nNew method ran in {:.2f}ms.\n'
    'Speedup: {:.1f}x'.format(old_t*1000, new_t*1000, old_t/new_t))))
# Output:
# Old method ran in 473.97ms,
# New method ran in 60.18ms.
# Speedup: 7.9x
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning a lot from you! And you're right. According to directions I was given, from a 32 bit binary, I'm supposed to ignore first 4, read in next 12, ignore next 4, and read the remaining 12. But I was getting smaller number of digits, 28, even for the max number of 268374016, so that's how I set 'thh = int(ths[-12:], 2)'

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out how to show code in a comment, and edit time expired. `thh = int(ths[-12:], 2)` Perhaps I should look for a way for binary numbers to have 32 digits to make things simpler.

Comment: @Chancheon, definitely in that case you should try the `np.logical_and` function, it is designed for this purpose. You'll want `high_bits = np.bitwise_and(a, bitmask_hi) >> (12+4)` where `bitmask_hi = bitmask << (12+4)` and `bitmask = (2**12-1)`.

Comment: Ai, I meant `np.bitwise_and`.